# Loading different css to IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, conditional-statements

So I'm trying to load a different css stylesheet if IE is detected.

My code:

```
<head>
<!-- other scripts and stylesheets -->

<!--[if IE]>
  <link href='css/index_ie.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>
  <link href='css/index.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<![endif]-->

<script>
(function() {
    if (typeof ActiveXObject === "undefined") {
        var s = document.createElement('link');
        s.href = "css/index.css";
        s.rel = "stylesheet";
        s.type = "type/css";
        document.documentElement.appendChild(s);
    }
    else {
        var s = document.createElement('link');
        s.href = "css/index_ie.css";
        s.rel = "stylesheet";
        s.type = "type/css";
        document.documentElement.appendChild(s);
    }
})();
</script>
</head>
```

This loads `index.css` correctly when not-IE browser. However this is not loading `index_ie.css` when IE is being used.

PS: testing with IE 10

Comment: for IE use this `var s = document.createElement('<link href="css/index_ie.css" rel="stylesheet" tye="text/css"/>');`

Comment: Also,  append it in the `head` element. `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s)`.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include content in browsers other than IE 9 and older, use a [slightly different syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx#dlrevealed):

```
<![if IE]>
  <link href='css/index.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<![endif]>
```

As it explains:

> The downlevel-revealed conditional comment enables you to include content in browsers that don't recognize conditional comments. Although the conditional comment itself is ignored, the HTML content inside it is not.

Though, note that conditional comments aren't fully supported after IE 9 (from the top of the same page):

> **Important** As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer supported by standards mode. Use feature detection to provide [effective fallback strategies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273396.aspx) for website features that aren't supported by the browser. For more info about standards mode, see [Defining Document Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325.aspx).